# Night light will still not work on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: night-light

I have tried out several solution of this problem described on other posts

Making a guest account, checking localization, trying red shift, turning on and off computer
Killing the process of night light before running red shift
Playing with manual, time, automatic
one screen, two screen
starting over again
reinstalling Gnome
Still night light will not work (neither red shift)

My screen wont change color

I used it before on another version of ubuntu and it used to work fine
I badly need this option because I draw on a wacom one and my eyes are suffering.

Comment: $Christie49 , not sure what you've tried. But the config that works for me are nvidia 510 with x11 and Nouveau with wayland. set time to all 0s. toggle night light on, wait for a couple of second.

Answer (score 0):

Ok
Night mode mysteriously came back on itself after an automatic update of ubuntu
Sorry, I don't think this post can help anyone